# background image not shoing up

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble getting the image to show up in my html

```
  <div id="header">
    <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"    codebase="/web/20120116002959oe_/http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=7,0,19,0" width="580" height="250">
                <param name="movie" value="images/stockbridgeiron.swf" />
                <param name="quality" value="high" />
                <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
                <embed src="images/stockbridgeiron.swf" width="580" height="250" quality="high" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" wmode="transparent"></embed>
        </object>
    </div>
```

css code

```
div#header {
    width: 928px;
    height: 250px;
    background: url(images/bg-header.jpg) top left no-repeat;
    text-align: right;

}
```

Comment: CSS is on the same path of folder images ?

Comment: the css file is in the main folder with index.html the images is in another folder called images i can go to  browser and go to the images folder and see the pic

Comment: you can see the full site @ http://www.higherpowerprofessionalservices.com/stockbridgeiron/

Answer (score 1):

It's because the background is overwritten with this selector:

```
.thrColFixHdr #header
```

You can add !important to your background property to override it.

```
background: url(images/bg-header.jpg) top left no-repeat !important;
```